# Search for string within files of a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help writing a light weight Python (v3.6.4) script to search for a single keyword within a directory of files and folders. Currently, I am using Notepad++ to search the directory of files, although I believe a Python script would be quicker?

Current script:

```
import os
key = input("Search For?: ")
folder = os.listdir("/")
for line in folder:
    if key in line:
        print(line)
```

EDIT: I am using Notepad++ to run these search queries.

The directory which I would like to search through has multiple levels of files within folders.

Comment: Currently you are using Python and writing the script in Notepad++, which is not a language in itself

Comment: Not sure what the question is here.. Unless we are talking about a massive directory on a slow server, they should be both pretty fast. You can also use the `dir /b/s *key* ` command from a shell

Comment: Why not just use grep?

Comment: @Chris_Rands No sir. I am writing the script in Python, but using Notepad++ as an alternative way to search the files (Find in files).

Comment: why not using grep or findstr ??

Comment: @Petru But you are searching **for** files and **not inside** them, right?

Comment: Also, the script you wrote above won't search "inside" the files, but will search for <word> in the file names in your directory

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I would like to search inside the file for the "keyword" not the file names. I understand my script won't do the job, i'm pretty rusty with Python and all I have written in my script has come from various other posts. Hence why I am here.

Comment: @Petru Then even your question does not do the job. The title should be **search for string within files of a directory** or smth.. Please edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Thanks for the suggestion..Done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really use `grep` (i.e. `grep -Ril "keyword" /`) or, if on Windows, `findstr` (`findstr /I /M /C:"keyword" /S \*`) but if you insist on doing it through Python you'll want to use [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) to *walk* through the root directory recursively, then open each found file and iterate over it to find if it contains your desired keyword, something like:

```
import os

keyword = input("Search For?: ")  # ask the user for keyword, use raw_input() on Python 2.x

root_dir = "/"  # path to the root directory to search
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir, onerror=None):  # walk the root dir
    for filename in files:  # iterate over the files in the current dir
        file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)  # build the file path
        try:
            with open(file_path, "rb") as f:  # open the file for reading
                # read the file line by line
                for line in f:  # use: for i, line in enumerate(f) if you need line numbers
                    try:
                        line = line.decode("utf-8")  # try to decode the contents to utf-8
                    except ValueError:  # decoding failed, skip the line
                        continue
                    if keyword in line:  # if the keyword exists on the current line...
                        print(file_path)  # print the file path
                        break  # no need to iterate over the rest of the file
        except (IOError, OSError):  # ignore read and permission errors
            pass
```

**TEST**: I've just tested it searching for `PyEnum_Type` through [CPython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython) cloned to `F:\.tmp\cpython-master` (thus `root_dir = r"F:\.tmp\cpython-master"`) on my local system running CPython 3.5.1 and the results are as expected:

```
Search For?: PyEnum_Type
F:\.tmp\cpython-master\Include\enumobject.h
F:\.tmp\cpython-master\Objects\enumobject.c
F:\.tmp\cpython-master\Objects\object.c
F:\.tmp\cpython-master\PC\python3.def
F:\.tmp\cpython-master\Python\bltinmodule.c
```

If it doesn't produce any results you're most likely setting your path wrong or you're searching for something that doesn't exist in the files under the defined `root_dir` (or your user doesn't have access to them).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I have compiled this and ran it with the correct directory and it just allows for an input and end, no data returned. no errors.

Comment: @Petru - check the test above.

Comment: Yes i was indeed using the wrong directory, I am running it on Windows not Linux. Thanks for this, I made some small modifications to print the line instead of the file name. Would you also be able to help me add a current directory function? so it can tell me what the current directory is that it is searching in? just so i know how close it is to ending. 

other than that thank you!

Comment: @Petru - the current directory being searched is always available in the `root` variable.