# Python Script to Loop and Search cell values (A2:A1700 - In xlsx) in directory folder having txt files and Save file names in .txt or .csv files

Tags: python, excel

I am new in scripting and currently working on project which requires me to read excel file having string from Cells A2 to A1700 in Sheet called "Index". I am trying to develop efficient python script to search each cell value from A2 to A1700 in "Index" Sheet against many text files in folder D:\Search Folder. If cell value is found in certain text files, file names has to be saved in new text file with file name same as cell Value in folder D:\Result Folder. So far i got the script to search string in text file however i do not have any idea about how to work with excel files.

[Search for string within files of a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110810/search-for-string-within-files-of-a-directory)

Thanks
Jignesh

Comment: could you show the code you used for your search in text file.

Comment: I added Link of code which i was using

Comment: Thanks. I posted an answer below, you can give it a try and come back if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to read excel files with something like (`pd.read_excel`). Then you can sompare those strings with the files in your Search Folder

Comment: Added Code which i was using. is it possible to modify to read excel cell values in sheet from A2 to A1700 in folder having text files and save file names in new text file with name equal to cell value

Comment: Yes it is possible, play with the pandas api is the best way to discover how